# The Labels on my window don't appear when the correct button is pressed

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a quiz that I made in python (Tkinter). For some reason, when I press a button, I doesn't show the label. I have no more info about this, because it does not even give me an error message.

here is the (bad) code:

```
from random import *

def submit():
    ca = 0
    ca = randint(1, 3)
    if ca == 1:
        if val1 == 1:
            score = Label(winroot, text="1 is Correct")
            score.pack()  
    if ca == 2:
        if val2 == 1:
            score = Label(winroot, text="2 is Correct")
            score.pack()
    if ca == 3:
        if val3 == 1:
            score = Label(winroot, text="3 is Correct")
            score.pack()
                    
win = Tk()
win.title("ziqp Quiz")
    
winroot = Frame(win)
winroot.pack()
    
question = Label(winroot, width=60, font=(10), text="Q")
question.pack()
    
val1 = IntVar()
val2 = IntVar()
val3 = IntVar()
    
option1 = Checkbutton(winroot, variable=val1, text="1", command=submit)
option1.pack()
    
option2 = Checkbutton(winroot, variable=val2, text="2", command=submit)
option2.pack()
    
option3 = Checkbutton(winroot, variable=val3, text="3", command=submit)
option3.pack()
    
nextb = Button(winroot, text="Submit", command=submit)
nextb.pack()
    
    
    
win.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is incomplete.
But the first thing that jumps out at me is that you have:

```
val1 = IntVar()
```

and in

```
def submit():
```

you're checking if:

```
if val1 == 1:
```

But val1 is an IntVar Tkinter variable, which you would check with:

```
val1.get()
```

In your code, your conditionals always fail, because `val1` will never be equal to `1`, because it's an `IntVar`

So, remember, with an `IntVar` (and all the other Tkinter variables), you assign with `.set()` and check with `.get()`, so...

```
val2.set(1)
if val2.get() == 1:
    print("Nice! They're equal!")
```

Addendum: in your case, since you're using the IntVars as variables for the Checkbuttons, the system is handling the "setting" of the values for the IntVars. But you still need to read their values using the `.get()` method.